# VB.NET 2010 dynamically adjusting datagridview color code

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am making a program that helps schedule employees and jobs for a company I am currently an intern for.  Most things have gone pretty well but I'm getting stuck on this particular problem:

I have a color code in place that shows at a quick glance what the likelihood of a job getting done on time will be.  **Green** is *very likely*, **yellow** is *somewhat likely*, and **red** is *unlikely*.  I would like this color code to be determined for each job based on the estimated time to complete every job that is due to be crated BEFORE the job in question.  I would like to do this for every job.

[This is a picture of the list of active jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3FVZ.jpg). Currently the program uses the sum of all the jobs, ones due before and after the one in question.  The only change I would like to make is to do this only for jobs before the one in question.

Here is the code I currently use to color code the "status" column

**EDIT**

The corrected code is now posted, big thanks to **vbnet3d**

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    Dim ts As TimeSpan
    Dim now As Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    Dim cdout As Date

    Me.JobDetailsBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("Crate_Date >= '" & now & "'")

    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim dayout As Date
        Dim dayout1 As Date
        Dim daysum As Integer = 0
        For x As Integer = 0 To i
            If (Date.TryParseExact(Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows(x).Cells(6).Value, pattern, Nothing, DateTimeStyles.None, dayout)) >= (Date.TryParseExact(Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value, pattern, Nothing, DateTimeStyles.None, dayout1)) Then
                daysum = daysum + Active_Jobs_List.Rows(x).Cells(45).Value
            End If
        Next
        If Date.TryParseExact(Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value, pattern, Nothing, DateTimeStyles.None, cdout) = True Then
            ts = cdout.Subtract(now)
            TextBox1.Text = Format(ts.TotalMinutes, 0) - daysum
        End If
        Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells("Cdate_Minus_Now").Value = TextBox1.Text

        If (Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells("Cdate_Minus_Now").Value) <= 2880 Then
            Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells("Current_Status").Style.BackColor = Color.Red


        ElseIf (Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells("Cdate_Minus_Now").Value) <= 5760 And Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells("Cdate_Minus_Now").Value > 2880 Then
            Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells("Current_Status").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow


        ElseIf (Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells("Cdate_Minus_Now").Value) > 5760 Then
            Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells("Current_Status").Style.BackColor = Color.Green

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I am very much a beginner to vb.net, so if you see any other problems with the code feel free to mention them.  Thank you all.

Comment: Just a thought... you might be able to shorten `ElseIf (Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells("Cdate_Minus_Now").Value) <= 999999 And Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells("Cdate_Minus_Now").Value > 5760 Then` to `ElseIf Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells("Cdate_Minus_Now").Value > 5760 Then`, assuming that you don't really have any upper limit.

Comment: And to clarify the question, you want to calculate the probability of a job being completed based on the *sum of all jobs prior to the current one*, correct?

Comment: Ah yes that is right, I will change that.

Comment: But yes, that is what I am aiming to do.  Ideally it would actually be all jobs on the same day and prior to the current one.  The current one just being whatever row "i" the program happens to be on

Comment: You should do a loop, beginning at the first record of the same day as the current row, and going to the current row, and sum all the values to that point.

Comment: For *same day*, are you referring to the *create date*?

Comment: Yes same day would be the crate day, or day they are crated once the job is completed.  Only crate dates before or equal to the crate date in interest should affect the ability to complete the job on time.  The loop certainly sounds like the way to go, I'm just not entirely sure how to set it up.  I just started coding in vb about 3 months ago so I'd still consider myself a beginner

Comment: Just FYI, you also do not need to specify the `Step` for + 1 incrementing. You are doing well for a beginner - glad to see you are taking on this kind of project!

Comment: `... determined for each job based on the estimated time` where is the estimated time?  Is it those hardcoded values used? do all jobs take the same amount of time?  The image shows 1 job per day (or person?) - can there be more than one; if so, how does the "before" element get determined.

Comment: Estimated time is calculated when the job is added based on the employees assigned to the job and their recorded skill level.  Typically the jobs average around the same time for similar size and type jobs.  You can add many more than one job per day, I just deleted everything to make the picture and question easier to understand.  Every job before the crate date listed and equal to the crate date listed are what effects that particular job.  There are 9 more forms that aren't shown here, this is just a small piece of the whole.

Comment: There is a simpler way to do that, but *where is the estimated time?* It isnt in the grid

Comment: I've no doubt there is haha.  I am still quite new to this, haven't had a ton of time to learn as this isn't my major, but I enjoy getting better at this.  It is hidden in the grid, but the user can see it when they add a job.  Its visible state is set to false.

Comment: Cheese and Rice...but *we* cant see it to know how to help!  It doesnt look like to code is even considering it

Comment: The code does consider it.  `daysum = daysum + Active_Jobs_List.Rows(x).Cells(45).Value`  Cell(45) is the estimated time.  For simplicity all estimated time will be equal for simply getting the code working initially, and that time is 270 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a loop within your main loop that creates a sum of all the jobs created on the same day as your current one, then use this sum in your logic.

Something along these lines:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows.Count - 1

Dim daySum As Integer

    For x As Integer = 0 To i
        If Active_Jobs_List.Rows(x).Cells("Crate_date").Value = Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells("Crate_date").Value Then
            daySum = daySum + Active_Jobs_List.Rows(x).Cells(45).Value
        End If
    Next


[Your current code - use daySum here]

Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  The code still runs in that setup, but I am still running into the sames issues.  If I add a crate date after another, it still affects the older crate date.  In order to compare the Active_Jobs_List.Rows(x).Cells("Crate_date") = Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells("Crate_date") I had to convert their values to strings, as it wouldn't let me compare the two with an "=" sign.  Not sure if that is throwing it off, but I didn't think it would

Comment: @JacobLatham Unless I'm missing something, you should be using it like `(Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells("Cdate_Minus_Now").Value) - daySum <= 5760`. I this way, you do not add it to the subsequent dates, but simply use it in the comparison statement. Also, you should edit your question to reflect the changes you have made.

Comment: I'm not sure I explained it accurately enough.  Really that column should be the crate date minus today's date (when the user logs on the program) minus the number of minutes it takes every job before it to get finished.  The code `TextBox1.Text = Format(ts.TotalMinutes, 0) - daysum` and `Me.Active_Jobs_List.Rows(i).Cells("Cdate_Minus_Now").Value = TextBox1.Text` should take care of that calculation I would think.  In the end that column should display how long the company has to finish the job.  Although like I said it is likely that something else I am doing here is incorrect

Comment: Okay... yes, I believe so, based on what you have already. On the note of what you can do better, use `Option Strict On` at the top of your code... You are inadvertently doing many implicit conversions (String to Integer and vice versa). This can hurt your program's performance and create bugs.

Comment: See my edit for the "=" issue... use `.Value`. I missed that initially.

Comment: @JacobLatham See my new edit... Declare `daySum` inside your main loop rather than outside, or, alternatively, set it to zero each time your main loop executes.

Comment: I've corrected the conversion issues, .value issues and moved daysum to be inside the loop.  The code looks much cleaner and I've edited my initial question to reflect that.  However, jobs with later crate dates still seem to be affecting those with prior crate dates.  I'll be looking over what I have to see if I can find any issues.  Again, thanks for all your help.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you have multiple loops. The code I suggested should go into your main loop where `i` is your index number.

Comment: Ah yes, not sure why I did that.  It works perfectly now, thank you very much, I greatly appreciate your patience and helpfulness.  A million upvotes for you!

Comment: No problem... glad to help!